# Content type form in infopath for Content type created in Visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, content-type, visual-studio-2012

I have created content type in Visual Studio and I have to apply infopath form to that content type in infopath. How do i proceed further ?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy content type in your site then attach it to list.

while creating infopath form select sharepoint list template then give url of your site(http://test.com/lists/testsample/allitems.aspx) then click next to select contenttype which you created in visual studio.

Comment: I think this is unlear to you 
here is complete sinario what i have done. I have created one content type in Visual studio and deployed this to site then what i have to do is, i have to add form to that content content type in infopath so that whereever i apply that content type to any list, then that form should appear.